# Area between $y=x^{6} - x$ and $x = y^{6} - y$?

Tags: definite-integrals

I realize that they are the same equations but with $x$ and $y$ switched, but I'm stuck from there on how to approach the problem.

Comment: Here's one possible approach: Find where the two curves intersect, and call that point $P_1$. Find the area between one of the curves and the line, $L$, going through the origin and $P_1$. Simply double that area, and that's your answer.

Comment: https://www.desmos.com/calculator/vrbqgbiyfd Here is the graph ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Inspired by [泥九奈加's comment](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2346702/area-between-y-x6-x-and-x-y6-y/2346718#comment4832547_2346702).

---

Note these functions are symmetric across the line $y=x$ (by definition, since they are inverses).  Likewise, solving for $f(x)=x$, we get

$$x^6-x=x\implies x^6=2x\implies\begin{cases}x=0\\x^5=2\implies x=\sqrt[5]2\end{cases}$$

Thus, the given integral is [given symmetrically](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/txo9xfhocm) by

$$I=2\int_0^{\sqrt[5]2}x-(x^6-x)~\mathrm dx$$

And I imagine you can take it from here?

Comment: @MichaelRozenberg Which statement?  That a function and its inverse are symmetric across $y=x$?  As far as I can tell, $y=-x$ and $x=-y$ are symmetric across $y=x$.

Comment: Simply Beautiful Art $(-5,5)$ is also common point. I think your solution is not full.

Comment: @MichaelRozenberg What do you mean?  I'm fairly certain that $f(x)\equiv x^6-x=x$ has no other real solutions and $f(f(x))=x$ has no other solutions either.  To what does $(-5,5)$ have anything to do here?

Comment: OK. I'll post a right solution.

Comment: it looks good to me @MichaelRozenberg

Comment: @MichaelRozenberg Well, I'll check your solution in the morning.  Good night!

Comment: @Simply Beautiful Art Try $y=x^2-2x$ and $x=y^2-2y$.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly we'll find  common points of our curves.

$x^6-x=y$ and $y^6-y=x$ gives $x^6=x+y$ and $y^6=x+y$, which gives $x=y$  or $x=-y$.

In the first case we have $x=0$ or $x=\sqrt[5]2$.

The second case gives an unique solution $x=0$, which says that our curves intersect in two points only and since our curves are symmetric with respect to the line $y=x$, we obtain that our area is
$$2\int\limits_{0}^{\sqrt[5]2}(x-(x^6-x))dx=...$$